# Confused with oxidation numbers

Tags: redox

If -2 is a oxidation number and 2- is the charge, then what is - by itself, is it a oxidation number or charge? As in $\ce{Ag+}$.

Also do you see $\ce{Cu + 2Ag+ -> Cu^{2+} + 2Ag}$ as a redox reaction?

Because I don't see any increase or increase in the oxidation number of any element in this equation. All I see is charges

Answer (score 3):

According to the [IUPAC gold book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/O04365.html), oxidation state is:

> A measure of the degree of oxidation of an atom in a substance. It is defined as the charge an atom might be imagined to have when electrons are counted according to an agreed-upon set of rules: (l) the oxidation state of a free element (uncombined element) is zero; (2) for a simple (monatomic) ion, the oxidation state is equal to the net charge on the ion;
> ...

Let's consider your reaction $Cu + 2Ag^+ \longrightarrow Cu^{2+} + 2Ag$ The superscripts represent charges. Reaction equations typically don't include oxidation states. In the reactants, $Cu$ has no charge and thus an oxidation state of 0 (rule 1). $Ag^+$ has a charge of +1 and thus an oxidation state of +1 (rule 2). In the products, $Cu^{2+}$ has a charge of +2 and thus an oxidation state of +2 (rule 2). $Ag$ has no charge and thus an oxidation state of 0 (rule 1).

In molecules, oxidation state can be thought of the charge of an atom when all bonds are treated as ionic. For example, in $H_2O$, Both $O-H$ bonds are polar and, since $O$ is more electronegative, all bonding electrons can be considered to belong to $O$. Thus, $O$ has 2 bonding pairs and 2 lone pairs for a total of 8. $O$ has 6 protons so it's oxidation state here is $6-8=-2$. Each $H$ has no electrons and 1 proton for an oxidation state of +1. The total oxidation state of the molecule is $2(+1)+-2=0$, which matches its charge.

Comment: To add, and to answer OP's ultimate question, "do you see this as a redox reaction?", the answer is yes. The left-hand side (Cu 0 oxidation #, Ag 1 oxidation #) --> right-hand side (Cu 2 oxidation #, Ag 0 oxidation #), Cu has oxidized (lost two electrons, increasing its Oxidation Number) and Ag has reduced (gained one electron, decreasing its Oxidation Number)

Answer (score 1):

In a chemical equation, the oxidation number is not provided, so any numbers are either the number of molecules, or the charge on the ions.

To determine the oxidation number, it is the number of electrons removed or added to the element to get to the stated charge. For example; $Cl^-$ has an oxidation number of -1; $Ca^{2+}$ has a oxidation number of +2; and in $SO_4^{2-}$, sulfur has an oxidation number of +6.